# Store sent mails using PHPMailer into Office365 account

Tags: email, imap, phpmailer, office365

I've started using `PHPMailer` with an `Office365` account and by now it works fine sending emails through `SMTP`. Anyway I need to store the sent emails, so I've tried @DavidRockin's [code](https://gist.github.com/DavidRockin/b4867fd0b5bb687f5af1) but I'm unable to make it store sent emails into the 'Sent items' folder (only the inbox works). Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if the sent folder exist and the correct name, it can have a similar meaning but different spelling.
First, use php_imap to get a list of folders, the one used for storing sent emails can be used with imap_append method

Comment: Hi Kassav', thanks for your help. I've tried using php's `imap_getmailboxes` (I didn't find that php_imap on the documentation) and I got a list of folders... The folder "Sent Items" is listed, but I'm still unable to store messages there...
I'm using the code `imap_append($mbox, $folder, $mail_content, "\\Seen");` to store them, is this wrong?

Comment: yes, it's imap_getmailboxes. Can you write here the imap error after append using imap_last_error?

Comment: I've solved the problem. From imap_last_error it was giving me the error that it wasn't able to find the proper mailbox with the name used ("Sent Items"). Tanking a second look at the list of mailboxes that comes back from the `imap_getmailboxes` I saw that also {outlook.office365.com} was a piece of the name (I thought it was a repetition of the host, so not necessary), so I added it and now it works as wanted. Thank you very much for your help